# How to optimize the left outer join with the case statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, left-join, case

I have two tables called genproductstoreindex and QAT_ListElid2  . I have joined with left outer join but it takes very long time to execute.

```
SELECT genproductstoreindex.[ElID]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN QAT_ListElid2.LeftTSMKEY IS NULL
            THEN genproductstoreindex.[TSMKEY]
        ELSE QAT_ListElid2.LeftTSMKEY + RightTSMKEY
        END
    ,[Numerical]
    ,[StringField]
    ,[DateField]
    ,[TableLevel]
    ,[TsmPath]
FROM genproductstoreindex
LEFT OUTER JOIN QAT_ListElid2 ON genproductstoreindex.ListElid = QAT_ListElid2.ListElid
```

To optimize the left outer join with case case statement i have replaced with below code but data looks incorrect . Please help me on this.

```
DECLARE @lefttsmkey NVARCHAR(30)

SET @lefttsmkey = NULL

IF @lefttsmkey IS NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT genproductstoreindex.[ElID]
        ,genproductstoreindex.[TSMKEY]
        ,[Numerical]
        ,[StringField]
        ,[DateField]
        ,[TableLevel]
        ,[TsmPath]
    FROM genproductstoreindex
    LEFT OUTER JOIN QAT_ListElid2 ON genproductstoreindex.ListElid = QAT_ListElid2.ListElid
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT genproductstoreindex.[ElID]
        ,QAT_ListElid2.LeftTSMKEY + RightTSMKEY AS [TSMKEY]
        ,[Numerical]
        ,[StringField]
        ,[DateField]
        ,[TableLevel]
        ,[TsmPath]
    FROM genproductstoreindex
    LEFT OUTER JOIN QAT_ListElid2 ON genproductstoreindex.ListElid = QAT_ListElid2.ListElid
END
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you will provide create tables and insert scripts.

Comment: use where condition in your first query-> where QAT_ListElid2.LeftTSMKEY IS NULL.

Comment: Which column belongs to which table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query looks fine. You want these indexes for it to run fast:

```
create index idx1 on genproductstoreindex(listelid);
create index idx2 on indexqat_listelid2(listelid, lefttsmkey);
```

If `RightTSMKEY` is a column in `indexqat_listelid2`, then add it to the second index.

You can make both these indexes covering by adding all columns used in the query to the related index. This will make them even more likely to be used. (If you find out the DBMS doesn't use one or the other, you can easily drop it again anyway.)

Comment: Thank you . can we optimize the left outer join

Comment: No. The left outer join is exactly what you want, or so I understand it. You want to show all `genproductstoreindex` and join `QAT_ListElid2` where available. You are doing exactly this. The query is fine, so all you can do is 1) provide indexes, 2) invest in hardware, 3) limit the data you are selecting. Right now you are selecting all `genproductstoreindex`. Ask yourself: is this really necessary? Doesn't it suffice to select only certain data from the table? If you need it all, then there is nothing I would change in your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT genproductstoreindex.[ElID]
    ,genproductstoreindex.[TSMKEY]
    ,[Numerical]
    ,[StringField]
    ,[DateField]
    ,[TableLevel]
    ,[TsmPath]
FROM genproductstoreindex with (nolock)
LEFT OUTER JOIN QAT_ListElid2 with (nolock) ON genproductstoreindex.ListElid = QAT_ListElid2.ListElid
where QAT_ListElid2.LeftTSMKEY IS NULL
UNION
SELECT genproductstoreindex.[ElID]
    ,QAT_ListElid2.LeftTSMKEY + RightTSMKEY AS [TSMKEY]
    ,[Numerical]
    ,[StringField]
    ,[DateField]
    ,[TableLevel]
    ,[TsmPath]
FROM genproductstoreindex with (nolock)
LEFT OUTER JOIN QAT_ListElid2 with (nolock) ON genproductstoreindex.ListElid = QAT_ListElid2.ListElid
where QAT_ListElid2.LeftTSMKEY IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You should always give a description to your solution how it solve the OP problem?